# emacs auto indenting .md file (in Fundamental mode)

Tags: emacs

I am editing a markdown file in emacs. Emacs automatically sets it to Fundamental mode and is auto indenting any newlines I enter. I tried disabling electric-indent-mode and didn't have any success. How do I disable this feature in this and other plain text files.

```
# Hello
    a
    b
    c
    d
```

Comment: `M-x markdown-mode`

Comment: `markdown-mode` is not part of Emacs, but you can obtain it from MELPA, and you can find information about it at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MarkdownMode

Comment: @FullDance Does this happen when you start Emacs like `emacs -Q`?  That will disable any customizations; I can't reproduce the problem with `emacs -Q`.  You can see what command is bound to `RET` with `C-h k RET` (default is `newline` in `fundamental-mode`).

Answer (score 0):

Install markdown package:

`M-x package-install RET markdown-mode RET`

it supports `.md` files as well.

Comment: This solves my problem with `.md` files, but what about other files I open in _Fundamental_ mode? Is the auto-indentation expected?